# Set userid into the session array how?

Tags: php

Hello I am posting maybe 4th question about this issue but nobody can help me so far, so let's start from the begining, what I need is simple I need to: Set userID variable from column name "userID' inside table named "users" into the Sessions array: $_SESSION['userID']

here is my login page code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once("config.php"); //include the settings/configuration
?>
<?php if( !(isset( $_POST['login'] ) ) ) { ?>
    <?php 
    //else look at the database and see if he entered the correct details
    } else {

session_start();
$usr = new Users;
$usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );
if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
header( 'Location: cursos.php' ) ;
$_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
```

and here is my user class which operates the function login:

```
public function userLogin() {
$success = false;
try{
$con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();  


$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$success = true;
if ($result!==false) { // Check there is a match
    $_SESSION['userID']= $result['userID'];
}


$success = true;

$con = null;
return $success;
}catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
return $success;
```

The code is working fine I just want to add addition to it which will get the userID value from the column of the users table inside the database ans store it to the $_SESSION['userID'] after user is loged in.

So any idea how to reach this goal in my code ? thanks!

Comment: The reason why you've not got any responses so far is probably because you should be clearer in what you have already done, and how it doesn't work the way you want it. Where is the problem, what *exactly* doesn't work in your code how?

Comment: The `header()` function should be after you set the $_SESSION values, so that you redirect the page after setting them. You also need to determine (read troubleshoot) that your login code is working.

Comment: This `$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];` is not secure. You are saving your users passwords in a text file in clear.

Comment: Hello Alexis what will be youur suggestion regarding this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the UserID from the table, you're going to have to do a `$stmt->fetch()` to load it first, then you can store it in your SESSION.

So after the execute in `function userLogin()` do:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If the user was found `$result` will then contain all of the fields from the users table. So:

```
if ($result!==false) { // Check there is a match
    $_SESSION['userID']= $result['userID'];
}
```

Comment: when I put the code after $stmt->execute(); after login I am getting white screen and noting is happening the function is not working.

Comment: Can you update your question to have the new code? A white screen usually indicates a syntax error (and display_errors is switched off). It's probably just a typo...

Comment: I wonder in the login page should I include something like $_SESSION['userID'] = ???

Comment: Sorry, my fault - there was a typo in my original answer, and you must have copied it before I corrected it! `$sth->fetch` should, of course, be `$stmt->fetch`

Comment: Finally a real answer and solution! Thank you very much I've spend 1 day trying to resolve it. Thanks again ! masterpiece...

Comment: No problem! Sorry about the earlier typo!